# Where does k3s store it's "/var/lib/kubelet/config.yaml" file?

Tags: configuration, k3s, kubelet

Referencing another [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54443743/124486), they suggest setting

```
evictionHard:
  imagefs.available: 1%
  memory.available: 100Mi
  nodefs.available: 1%
  nodefs.inodesFree: 1%
```

In the file `/var/lib/kubelet/config.yaml`. However, I do not see that file in my k3s distribution of kubernetes. Where is this file located with k3s?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## `/etc/rancher/k3s/config.yaml`

***Note, `/etc/rancher/k3s/config.yaml` not `/etc/rancher/k3s/k3s.yaml`! You may have to create the file if it doesn't exist.***

[K3s doesn't have a dedicated kubelet service. It's integrated into k3s.](https://github.com/k3s-io/k3s/issues/5213#issuecomment-1061135298) So it's [configured only with the `--kubelet-arg` flag](https://rancher.com/docs/k3s/latest/en/installation/install-options/server-config/#customized-flags-for-kubernetes-processes) to k3s. But you can [add Kubelet config directives to your `config.yaml` (`/etc/rancher/k3s/config.yaml`)](https://github.com/k3s-io/k3s/issues/5488#issuecomment-1106227357),

```yaml
kubelet-arg:
  - "kube-reserved=cpu=500m,memory=1Gi,ephemeral-storage=2Gi"
  - "system-reserved=cpu=500m, memory=1Gi,ephemeral-storage=2Gi"
  - "eviction-hard=memory.available<500Mi,nodefs.available<10%"
```

Which would look like,

```
kubelet-arg:
  - "eviction-hard=imagefs.available<case>,memory.available<case>,nodefs.available<case>,nodefs.inodesFree<case>"
```

You can find more information at,

- [*"Customized Flags for Kubernetes Processes"*](https://rancher.com/docs/k3s/latest/en/installation/install-options/server-config/#customized-flags-for-kubernetes-processes)
- [*"K3S Configuration File"*](https://rancher.com/docs/k3s/latest/en/installation/install-options/#configuration-file)