# Where can I find the default arguments supplied to the internal Kublet Service in k3s?

Tags: k3s, kubelet

If I want to find the default-arguments to the internal Kublet service, where can I find these documented?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't able to find them documented, but I did find them in the [code in `agent_linux.go`](https://github.com/k3s-io/k3s/blob/491aa11e1068cc6605598822dc456ef1fc18f4f1/pkg/daemons/agent/agent_linux.go#L67) (note there are difference options for [windows](https://github.com/k3s-io/k3s/blob/491aa11e1068cc6605598822dc456ef1fc18f4f1/pkg/daemons/agent/agent_windows.go#L59))

You can see them here,

```go
argsMap := map[string]string{
    "healthz-bind-address":         bindAddress,
    "read-only-port":               "0",
    "cluster-domain":               cfg.ClusterDomain,
    "kubeconfig":                   cfg.KubeConfigKubelet,
    "eviction-hard":                "imagefs.available<5%,nodefs.available<5%",
    "eviction-minimum-reclaim":     "imagefs.available=10%,nodefs.available=10%",
    "fail-swap-on":                 "false",
    "cgroup-driver":                "cgroupfs",
    "authentication-token-webhook": "true",
    "anonymous-auth":               "false",
    "authorization-mode":           modes.ModeWebhook,
}
```